# Dropdown buffer menu for emacs 25.1 doesn't show new buffers

Tags: emacs, menu

I have just installed emacs 25.1 on a machine with an Ubuntu 17.04 OS. However, drop-down buffer list only list the 3 initial buffers (i.e. GNU Emacs, scatch and messages), regardless of which buffers I've opened. `C-x C-b` gives me an accurate list of open buffers, and the value of my `buffers-menu-max-size` is 10.

What can I do so that the drop-down menu for buffers accurately reflects my open buffers and can be used to switch between them?

Comment: Does this behavior persist when launching with `emacs -Q`?

Comment: No, it does not. The difference does not seem, however, to be the -Q option, but instead, when I open emacs from a terminal, everything works. When I use Ubuntu's launcher to start emacs, I get the problem I noted. I still don't know how to fix, but now expect I need to ask a different question.

Comment: Interesting.  Does `M-: (redisplay)` or `M-: (menu-bar-update-buffers)` help at all?

Comment: No, that doesn't seem to do anything. The difference seems to be that when I type emacs in a terminal, it's equivalent to typing /usr/bin/emacs, which is a softlink to /etc/alternatives/emacs, which is a softlink to /usr/bin/emacs25-x.  Ubuntu's launcher runs the command '/usr/bin/emacs25 %F', which softlinks to emacs25-x. I assume this means /usr/bin/emacs25-x. When I run /usr/bin/emacs25-x *directly*, I recreate my problem, when I use the softlink through /etc/alternatives/emacs, my problem goes away. I don't understand this at all...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with emacs 25.2.2 running in ubuntu 18.04. I followed user1245262's suggestion and ran it from terminal, and the problem went away. So it seems to be related to default behaviour of Ubuntu Unity, where menus for a window are shown in the Unity menu bar at the top, rather than in the window's title bar.  By changing this default behaviour (settings->appearance->behavior) you can then launch emacs from the Unity launcher and the buffer menu problem is fixed.

Comment: Actually, I wrote too soon...I was still having problems with the buffer menu not showing all buffers and not being able to switch between buffers (via the menu). So I've resorted to starting emacs from terminal.